# How to pass session_id or cookies in phantomjs or casperjs

Tags: phantomjs, session-cookies, casperjs

Hi I am trying to do the following thing using the phantomjs and casperjs.
Create an automated script that's going to do the following step.

- Go to the url.
- Login to the url using username/pw.
- After login redirect to a tab in the page which opens another portal.

So my issue is when I try to open the other portal it is not passing my credentials (cookies or session id) as a result its redirecting in the page but fails to keep the current session alive.

My question is how can I pass the `session_id` to the redirecting url.

My piece of code is in below:

After logging to the page it is trying to verify the page is loaded and in debug mode printing the cookies:

The below step is able to print the cookies

Enter code here:

```
casper.then(function(){
                //this.echo('-------------$$$ trying to print cookies ' + casper_cookies, 'WARNING' );  

                this.waitForSelector('#navigation', function then(){

        this.echo('------$$$Portal found navigationbar','INFO'  );

                                this.echo('-------------$$$ trying to print cookies using phantomjs: ', 'WARNING' );
//               this.echo('Browser Cookie: ' + this.evaluate(function() {
//            return document.cookie;
//}));
                var cookies = page.cookies;
                console.log('Listing cookies:');
                for(var i in cookies) {
                console.log(cookies[i].name + '=' + cookies[i].value);
                };
......
......code

,
```

In my next step I am trying to redirect to another page:

```
casper.thenOpen(NewUrl, function() {
     this.echo("-------$$$Trying to open newUrl", 'INFO');

        this.waitForSelector('#page', function then(){    
        this.echo('---------$$$ We have logged in ' + this.getTitle() + ' Page', 'INFO');   

       },

       function timeout() {
           this.echo("--------------$$$could not  found   ----------------- ");
       casper.exit(return_codes.protocol_error);
   });
 });
------------
```

So it is able to redirect to the page but fails to pass the `session_id`.

How I can add the `session_id`. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You don't need to manage cookies manually (usually). Do you open next page in the same script?

Comment: I am doing it in the same script. Actually in the casper.thenOpen(NewUrl, function() {}----;

Comment: Opening NewURL (the url that I have defined in the veraibale)
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://****/****/*****/******=idB9F1A5C663, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true

Than dynamically redirecting and having error (please help)
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://*******/****/app/**Login?error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=Unsupported%20response%20types:%20%5Bcode%26scope%3Dread%5D, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true

Comment: FYI In the browser, if I log in to the portal and put the URL of the bad request it is able to open the page as it is communicating with the main portal. but in automation script, if fails to get the cookies or session id

Comment: Cookies are handled automatically by PhantomJS (during one run of a script). Your issue could be unrelated to cookies, `unsupported_response_types` looks suspicious.